$u \in L^2(0,T, H^{1}_0)$ and $u_t \in L^p(0,T,H^{-1})$ is $u \in C([0,T], X)$
Suppose $u \in L^2(0,T; H^{1}_0(U))$ and $u_t \in L^p(0,T;H^{-1}(U))$, it is know for example when $p = 2$ that $u \in C[[0,T];L^2(U)]$ but do we have any such general result for $p < 2$,

No. This embedding result is sharp.

@daw I see. And what if replace $L^2$ by some other space?

It is true for $X= H^{-1}$ (trivially) and then also for some spaces between $H^{-1}$ and $L^2$, but I am no export in this.
